# Does the windows 8 store only support windows RT?

Tags: game-development, appstore, windows-8, portability

I'm in a project for creating a game engine and eventually a game, and we need ideas on how to get our game out into the internet.

I had an idea with putting it onto the windows 8 store at a low cost(or free) in order to get the word out, but **does the windows 8 store only support apps programmed in windows RT?**

Our game will be built in C++ / OpenGL / GLEW / Actionscript / GLM / etc.. , so we won't be using any windows RT functionality at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

You can advertise in Windows Store, but you need to handle payment, deployment and installation yourself.

Comment: Being a Windows8 user and having browsed the store I support this answer. There are desktop apps but none include a download button. Just links to external pages.

Answer (score 1):

No.

From [White papers for Windows Store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465413.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> This paper addresses various aspects of developing Windows Store apps for Windows RT. **The bulk of Windows Store app development practices are the same for both Windows 8 and Windows RT**, but in a few scenarios Windows RT and the hardware particular to these PCs may require special consideration.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with development practices, but with deployment and installation.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can following the guidelines for publishing an app on window store, it should not matter. But do check before hand the dll's and component you are using, will be allowed on windows store or not other at the last minute when trying to publish the app it will be a big disappointment.

I know for you it does not allow Win32 based dll's. and Some of the pretty common c++ static libraries are also not allowed